Authorship for Publishing Master’s Research Paper – First Author vs. Second Author?
My tutor has approached me with an opportunity to publish my master’s dissertation research, which examines the relationship between social media sentiment and cryptocurrency dynamics. I’ve been given two options regarding how the paper will be written and how authorship will be credited:

I write the paper myself using my portfolio and final report as a foundation. My tutor would be the corresponding author and second author, while I’d be named first author. This option would involve writing a formal research paper (including a literature review, methodology, results, etc.) and also making some technical improvements to the analysis.
My tutor writes the paper, making all necessary improvements and finalizing the submission. I’d be listed as second author, and my tutor would be first author and corresponding author.

I don’t plan on pursuing a career in academia or publishing a lot of research papers in the future, but I do see value in having at least one paper published to enhance my CV. I understand that being first author holds more prestige, but the time and stress involved in doing all the writing and technical adjustments myself might be a bit overwhelming.
Is first authorship worth the extra workload if I’m not looking to pursue academia long-term? How important would second authorship be in terms of the recognition it offers, especially for non-academic careers?

Given your relative lack of experience in writing academic papers and your lack of interest in a career in academia, I'd suggest that 2 should be fine. It would be better if there is a "contributions" section in which it is clear that the work was originally yours.
Corresponding author is a job, not an honor, and the tutor is probably better prepared for that.
I would suggest, however, staying connected in the process, reading all drafts and making suggestions as needed. That will give you some experience being adjacent to the process while not responsible for it.
I would answer differently, however, if you plan a career in academia. Lot of work, yes, a bit more prestige, yes, but the experience is the more important thing.
Your tutor would probably find first authorship more valuable than you would (given what you say) and a certain amount of generosity in such things is valuable since it opens the door to future collaboration should you change directions.

As @Buffy already mentioned, if the space allows, it is better to add a contribution section such as: (Author1: draft writing, conceptualization, implementation, evaluation, ...; Author2: supervision, paper writing, ...). With this, you preserve your contribution forever; and the position does not really matter (unless formally required, like in PhD regulation). However, if you plan to submit to a conference, you might not have enough space to add this section.
